# print the string in between 2 conditions of text file in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, text

I am new to python.I am struggling to print the string in between conditions of text file.My text file contains information below

```
03:37:59 CONFIRM 03.37.59 IS-0008 SS-XYZ  SSU-BSS  AB-008966 CTL-I001234   
03:37:59 123HTSA TVP5                                                      
08:12:19 SNAP 290D 08.12.20 CX-A TU-BSS ZRE-BSS IS-3 
08:12:19 PSW-07151000 813264 00000000 2967561E      
08:12:19 PGM-BA13 CODE-U00BA1302 TERM-000000A  

/*After this a few lines of data display*/

08:12:19 GOOD BYE TAKE CARE
```

Third Line has **“SNAP”** and “IS-“
 Line 5 has “**PGM-XXXX**” where XXXX = program name and “CODE-XXXXXXXXX” XXXXXXXXX = type of **Snap** dump as coded.
        This will be followed by a few lines of data display. The number of lines is variable and can change. 
        The last line will be **“GOOD BYE TAKE CARE”**

My output should be

```
08:12:19 SNAP 290D 08.12.20 CX-A TU-BSS ZRE-BSS IS-3 
08:12:19 PSW-07151000 813264 00000000 2967561E      
08:12:19 PGM-BA13 CODE-U00BA1302 TERM-000000A        

/*After this a few lines of data display*/

08:12:19 GOOD BYE TAKE CARE
```

I have tried but i want to print upto **08:12:19 GOOD BYE TAKE CARE**

```
with open("TEXT.txt", "r") as file:
output = ""
for line in file.readlines():
    if "CTL" in line:
        output += line
        print(output)
```

Comment: How are you struggling? Do you have any code already?

Comment: You are explaining what you have but there is not clear statement what you want and how that relates to what you have. Making that clear is the first part of automating it.

Comment: with open("TEXT.txt", "r") as file:
    output = ""
    for line in file.readlines():
        if "CTL" in line:
            output += line
            print(output)

Comment: @Venkatesan, ok, show how exactly should look the expected result

Comment: Is the indentation in your code exactly how it appears in this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
printing = False
with open('text.txt') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        if line[9:13] == 'SNAP':
            printing = True
        if printing:
            print (line.strip())
        if line == '08:12:19 GOOD BYE TAKE CARE':
            break
```

Initially the Boolean variable `printing` is set to `False` so that printing is disabled. Lines are read in a loop. When a line is read with 'SNAP' in the special location `printing is set to`True` to enable printing. In this condition lines are printed as soon as they are read. When a line is read containind 'GOOD BYE [etc]' the loop is broken and the script comes to an end.

EDIT: If you want to end printing prior to 'GOOD BYE [etc]' then the script could be the following.

```
printing = False
with open('text.txt') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        if line[9:13] == 'SNAP':
            printing = True
        if line.strip() == '08:12:19 GOOD BYE TAKE CARE':
            break
        if printing:
            print (line.strip())
```

Notice especially that `line` must be stripped of end-of-line characters to test for equality.

Comment: Your code is printing upto the GOOD BYE TAKE CARE (before this line).If i want to print GOOD BYE TAKE CARE line means what should i do? can u please help on this?

Comment: I've edited my answer according to what I think you may mean.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly that you just need to print lines staring with the line containing SNAP and IS-, then how about this?

```
import re
with open("TEXT.txt", "r") as file:
    output = ""
    ok = False
    for line in file:
        if re.search('SNAP.*IS-', line):
            ok = True
        if ok:
            output += line
    print(output)
```